# ClassNotFoundException: org.jaxen.JaxenException in ear file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classpath

I'm baffled by what is going on here. I keep getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jaxen.JaxenException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
        ... 51 more
```

Yet, this class file IS in my ear and also on the 'Class-Path' attribute of both my ejb's manifest and my ear's manifest file. Is there somewhere else I need to add the jaxen jar to have it be seen by other jar's in the ear? Do all jar's in a ear share the same classpath?

**EDIT #1**

There is this too:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jaxen/JaxenException
        at org.dom4j.DocumentFactory.createXPath(DocumentFactory.java:230)
        at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractNode.createXPath(AbstractNode.java:207)
        at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractNode.selectNodes(AbstractNode.java:164)
```

**EDIT #2**

I am deploying to glassfish v3.1 and the lib jars are at the root of the ear file, like so:

```
-foo.ear
--\META-INF
--lib1.jar
--lib2.jar
--jaxen-1.1.1.jar
```

**EDIT #3**

I have tried deploying to another version of GF and it appears to work, I think it might be a bug in the version I'm using. I've opened a forum thread [here](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/classnotfoundexception-orgjaxenjaxenexception-ear-file-only-certain-gf-version).

**EDIT #4**

I had dom4j in the app server lib directory but not jaxen on the server. Adding the jaxen lib fixed this.

Comment: Is it in the `lib/` directory of your EAR?

Comment: Are you using any app container (ie. jboss, weblogic, etc)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need the jaxen jar in your **servers** lib folder

http://jaxen.codehaus.org/releases.html

Comment: Can you not pack it in to the ear?

Comment: Somehow you ended yo being right - I had dom4j on the server lib and didn't realize it.

Comment: Does anyone know why this isn't picked up at build time as a transitive dependency?

Answer (score 3):

Any jars that are in the `lib/` directory of your EAR will automatically be loaded.

> Another example is the common task of bundling a number of library JAR files with an application. By default, the lib directory under the application root is reserved for library files. Previously, you had to add a manifest entry to the application module, which could be a tedious task.

[Source](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/intro_ee5/)

Comment: That means they are on the "shared path" more or less, right? Also, is this a standard across application servers?

Comment: If it works on Glassfish, then it *should* work on every other server since Glassfish is the reference implementation. I use WebLogic 10 at work, and the `lib/` is automatically loaded as well. I added a link to some documentation that explains it.

Comment: I apologize, I was wrong (yet again...sigh). I've got jaxen in the lib dir of he packed ear and the problem persists :(