# NoClassDefFoundError org/jaxen/JaxenException in Jboss EAP6

Tags: jakarta-ee, classloader, noclassdeffounderror, jdom, jboss-eap-6

I deploy my code in Jboss EAP6 ear's `/lib` folder, it calls `org.jdom.XPath.newInstance()`, which calls `org.jdom.JaxenXPath`, which calls the `org.jaxen` package.

I do have the Jaxen JAR in my Jboss core modules at `jboss\modules\system\layers\base\org\jaxen\main\jaxen-1.1.3.redhat-4.jar`

But still, I get a NoClassDefFoundError for org/jaxen/JaxenException (and I guess for all the package). If I copy that jaxen JAR in my ear's /lib folder, the error disappears, so I guess it's a Jboss classloader issue, but I used Jboss modules packages before and it never happened. What is going on?

PS : [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072232/classnotfoundexception-org-jaxen-jaxenexception-in-ear-file) doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jaxen Jboss module is private (see `module.xml` in the same folder as the JAR). I had to add the following line to my calling JAR's manifest:

```
Dependencies: org.jaxen
```

Comment: ...and because it is private you need to be prepared for it to disappear altogether - even after a minor update. If your application uses these classes you should either deploy them in your application or add them in your own module.